# C# Programming How to grep columns/lines from Text File?

Tags: c#, file, grep

I have a C# console program which main functions should let a user grep lines / columns from a log text file.

An Example within the text file the user wishes to grep a group of all the related lines starting from a particular date etc. "Tue Aug 03 2004 22:58:34" to "Wed Aug 04 2004 00:56:48". Therefore after processing, the program would then output  all the data found within the log text files between the 2 dates.

Could someone please advise on some codes that I could use to grep or create a filter to retrieve the neccessary text/data from the file? Thanks!

C# Program Files:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Testing
{
class Analysis
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Read the file lines into a string array.
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Test\ntfs.txt");

        System.Console.WriteLine("Analyzing ntfs.txt:");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);

            //  ***Trying to filter/grep out dates, file size, etc****
            if (lines = "Sun Nov 19 2000")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Print entire line");
            }
        }

        // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Log Text File Example:

```
Wed Jul 21 2004 16:58:48   499712 m... r/rrwxrwxrwx 0        0        8360-128-3 
C:/Program Files/AccessData/Common Files/AccessData LicenseManager/LicenseManager.exe

Tue Aug 03 2004 22:58:34    23040 m... r/rrwxrwxrwx 0        0        8522-128-3 
C:/System Volume Information/_restore{88D7369F-4F7E-44D4-8CD1-
F7FF1F6AC067}/RP4/A0002101.sys

23040 m... r/rrwxrwxrwx 0        0        9132-128-3 
C:/WINDOWS/system32/ReinstallBackups/0003/DriverFiles/i386/mouclass.sys

23040 m... r/rrwxrwxrwx 0        0        9135-128-4 C:/System Volume 
Information/_restore{88D7369F-4F7E-44D4-8CD1-F7FF1F6AC067}/RP4/A0003123.sys

23040 m... r/rrwxrwxrwx 0        0        9136-128-3 
C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/mouclass.sys

Tue Aug 03 2004 23:01:16   196864 m... r/rrwxrwxrwx 0        0        4706-128-3 
C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/rdpdr.sys

Tue Aug 03 2004 23:08:18    24960 m... r/rrwxrwxrwx 0        0        8690-128-3 
C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/hidparse.sys
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as a quick fix for the specific example:

```
if (line.StartsWith("Sun Nov 19 2000"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

You could use `Contains` to find a substring within the line.

Note that loading the whole file in an array won't scale well for very large logs. We can look into fixing that if it's an issue for you - but let's take things slowly :)

Comment: Does the "StartsWith" only read the beginning? Cause there are some lines do not start with a date as a form with multiple processes happening during the same time. Thanks.

Comment: @JavaNoob: Yes, "StartsWith" only checks for the beginning of the line - which is why I mentioned "Contains" as well... although it sounds like your multiple processes are possibly corrupting your log files, which would be worth fixing as a separate matter.

Comment: The multiple processes are used correctly as the logs are meant as a usage for MACtimes. I've edited the logs sections in my question above so please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @JavaNoob: I don't know what you mean by MACtimes... are log lines meant to start with dates or not? If they are, but sometimes you see dates in the middle of a line due to multiple processes writing to the log concurrently, that's a problem IMO.

Answer (score 5):

You could do this using `Regex` to select matching lines in a richer way than `string.Contains` allows.

Not sure why you are reinventing `findstr.exe` though.

For large files you might find [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) (.Net 4 only) performs better - this reads the same lines but allows you to process them in a `foreach` and other `IEnumerable` scenarios without loading the entire file into RAM at once.

Comment: Reps up for the ReadLines idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a grep style method I use in testing:

```
    public static List<string> FileGrep(string filePath, string searchText)
    {
        var matches = new List<string>();

        using (var f = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            var s = new StreamReader(f);

            while (!s.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = s.ReadLine();

                if (line != null && line.Contains(searchText)) matches.Add(line);   
            }

            f.Close();
        }

        return matches;
    }
```